# TableLayout panel - border color and offset

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, border, tablelayoutpanel

I am developing a C# winform project on building facade systems.This project uses a TableLayoutPanel control and all cells has Pictureboxes with border style is fixed.

I want to draw a line or border around this lightning area.
I used cellpaint event and achieved to draw. I want to give some offset and also i want to change draw color same as pictureboxes(borderstyle fixed)

These are codes:

```
private void tlp1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (confirmedView)
            {
              Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100), 2);
                if(e.Column== cellStartColumnIndex|| e.Column == cellStartColumnIndex+1 || e.Column == cellStartColumnIndex + 2)
                {
                    if(e.Row == cellStartRowIndex)
                    {
                        var topLeft = e.CellBounds.Location;
                        var topRight = new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top);
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, topLeft, topRight);
                    }
                }
                if (e.Row == cellStartRowIndex || e.Row == cellStartRowIndex + 1)
                {
                    if (e.Column == cellStartColumnIndex|| e.Column == cellStartColumnIndex+3)
                    {
                        var topLeft = e.CellBounds.Location;
                        var topRight = new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom);
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, topLeft, topRight);
                      }
                 }
          }
        }
```

[image]

Edit:

With using color pick-up application, the property(Argb) of the color can be taken. So i defined new pen with desired color

```
 Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100), 2);
```

For border offset, I get @Jimi's advised that using padding property.

Comment: If you want to draw over several 'cells' why not use the Paint event of the TLP? Just get the coordinates right!

Comment: If you add Padding to the TLP, the default external border is moved in-wards. The internal borders are not affected. If you don't set the CellBorderStyle, you can then draw your border, with the offset defined by the Padding. The BorderColor is Color.Gray. -- Not clear what `cellStartColumnIndex` and `cellStartRowIndex` are used for. Do you mean to apply this custom border to a specific selection of Cells?

Comment: Note that if you just need to draw a standard (1 pixel) border, you can add `ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, [Your TLP].ClientRectangle, Color.Gray, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);` to the Paint event handler of your TLP. Othrewise, use the `Graphics.DrawRectangle()`. -- The Color of the default Border of a PictureBox may change based on the background color of its Parent.